# Create a two year comparison chart with monthly average emission values

Tags: google-earth-engine

I've been struggling in creating a chart to compare monthly data for two years. So far, I've been to do this graph.

[image].

However, I'd like to create this chart:

[image]

This is the code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/60de9bd5003dbd0e54f5c2045c70af78

Do you have any recommendation of command I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a feature collection of the input values for the graph, and than graph that using a group property (the year):

```
// create a chart with a reducer
var features = MonthlyNO2.map(function(image){
  var propVal = image.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.sum(), CDMX.geometry(), 5000);

  return ee.Feature(null, image.toDictionary(image.propertyNames()))
              .set(propVal)
})
var chart = ui.Chart.feature.groups(features, 'month', 'NO2_column_number_density', 'year')
print(chart)
```

[link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/14c09f5fcad9d56bbf0e4fe58fcf2cd3)